# Decodable вручную на Swift 4

Tags: json, ios, swift

JSON, который я получаю имеет следующий вид:

```
{
"market_cap":
             [
                 [1522184067000,135864381010],
                 [1522184367000,136121172842]
             ],

     "price":    
             [
                 [1522184067000,8018.88],
                 [1522184367000,8034.03]
             ],

     "volume":    
             [
                 [1522184067000,5738440000],
                 [1522184367000,5773040000]
             ]
}
```

Самый простой способ автоматически привести данные, который я нашел, выглядит так:

```
struct CoinData {

    let marketCap: [[Double]]
    let price: [[Double]]
    let volume: [[Int]]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case marketCap = "market_cap"
        case price = "price"
        case volume = "volume"

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я хочу получить в свойство 'marketCap' не объект типа [[Double]], а, например, [MarketCap], где тип MarketCap, внутри себя имеет еще один объект MarketCapData со свойствами 'date' и 'value', значениями которых являются первый и второй элемент массива, соответственно.

Код, получившийся у меня не работает, а ошибку, увы, я не вижу.

```
struct CoinChartData: Decodable {

    struct MarketCapArray: Decodable {

        struct MarketCapValues: Decodable {
            let date: Int
            let value: Double
            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case date
                case value
            }

            init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                let date = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .date)
                let value = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .value)
                self.date = date
                self.value = value
            }
        } // MarketCapValues

        var array: [Double]
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case array
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            let array = try values.decode([Double].self, forKey: .array)
            self.array = array
        }
    } // MarketCapArray

    let marketCap: [MarketCapArray]
    let price: [[Double]]
    let volume: [[Int]]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case marketCap = "market_cap"
        case price = "price"
        case volume = "volume"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем случае нужно немного по-другому это разбирать. Напишу более общий упрощенный пример по аналогии с Вашим.

1 "Получаем" JSON:

```
let data = """
{
    "value": [
        [123.4, 12343],
        [31, 245255.1]
    ]
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

2 Стандартный массив из того что получили (для проверки/сравнения):

```
struct FirstTestStructure: Codable {
    let value: [[Double]]
}
// MARK: - Проверяем
print(try! JSONDecoder().decode(FirstTestStructure.self, from: data)) // только для проверки, не повторять "!" в реальной жизни. :)
```

3 Пишем реализацию под свои желания, пример:

```
struct SecondTestStructure: Codable {
    let value: [SomeObject]

    struct SomeObject: Codable {
        let key: Double
        let value: Double
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        value = try values.decode([[Double]].self, forKey: .value).flatMap { element -> SomeObject? in
            // MARK - если гарантированно будет по 2, то можно проверку убрать, 
            // но лишний раз перестраховаться не помешает.
            if element.count == 2 {
                return SomeObject(key: element[0], value: element[1])
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
// MARK: - проверяем.
try! JSONDecoder().decode(SecondTestStructure.self, from: data).value.forEach { print($0) }
```